# Queries containing backslashes are not giving any results

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query: `SELECT file, path, type FROM testDB WHERE path=?`.
The prepared statement is getting a string containing backslashes like this: *C:\Users\Sven\Desktop*

This is not returning anything, although I have stored exactly this C:\Users\Sven\Desktop in my MySQL database. In order to query the statement in phpMyAdmin I have to add one extra backslash, which gives me the result I want. I suspected that this was the issue making my prepared statement return nothing so I change the query directly to both `SELECT file, path, type FROM testDB WHERE path = 'C:\Users\Sven\Desktop'` and `SELECT file, path, type FROM testDB WHERE path = 'C:\\Users\\Sven\\Desktop'` but still nothing returned. What can be wrong?

The important stuff:

```
if (isset($_GET["path"])) {
    $sql1 = "SELECT `file`, `path`, `type` FROM testDB WHERE path=?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["path"]);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testDB";
    $result = $link->query($sql);
}
if ($result) {
    if ($result->num_rows) {
```

The GET is getting `$row['path']`.

Comment: Show us the URL where you have the path.

Comment: ``bind_param("s", $_GET["path"])`` may be an issue, where is the variable to be bound in this query. Also you may need to use [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) since your variable is coming from ``$_GET``, so ``$stmt->bind_param('s', rawurldecode($_GET['path']));``

Comment: @JayBlanchard The path is just something I have in my database. I just want to check it with a query, not access it or anything like that. It is not a URL or anything.

Comment: `$_GET['path']` leads me to believe you have a path in your URL. What is in that variable?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand. But this is not a path to any page or anything. It is just a local path from my computer that I want to check with a query, I am using a web interface for my data management tool. I am sending this to get btw: echo "<td><a href='http://myurl.com?path=" . $row['path'] . "'>" . $row['path'] . "<a/></td>";

Comment: What is in that variable? You're using that variable to retrieve the data from the database, so we need to know what is in the variable. Look at the answers you're getting - they all assume the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure `path` is stored properly in your database? It could be double escaped, or not escaped in the first place so it's actually `C:UsersSvenDesktop`. What does your `$_GET` variable actually contain?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `addslashes` and `rawurldecode`:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", addslashes(rawurldecode($_GET['path']));
```

`rawurldecode` will get the path from `$_GET` and return a string in which the sequences with percent (%) signs followed by two hex digits have been replaced with literal characters. This is needed because the path may contain spaces which may be converted to `%20` and have to be converted back for search. (Maybe not needed in your specific case, but it will be useful in more cases).

`addslashes` is also required, it returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash ().

Answer (score -1):

In database, table menu, field content I inserted:

```
C:\Users\Sven\Desktop
```

I just try like this:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kartedium_cmslight', "root", "");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE content = ?');
$id="C:\\Users\\Sven\\Desktop";
$stmt->execute([$id]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['content'];
}
?>
```

Result is ok:

```
C:\Users\Sven\Desktop
```

Comment: The code looks fine, but I have no idea what you'd need two fields.

Comment: You are right, do not need two fields, only one with double backslesh.